# Calculating the maximum possible length for a string matching a regular expression in xsd (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, regex, xsd

I am working with XSDs, and I have access to the pattern from the XSD as a string. An example:

```
<xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{8}"/>
```

gives me the C# string

```
string pattern = "[0-9]{8}";
```

From the pattern string I obtain from the XSD (which could be any valid XSD pattern entry), I am trying to work out the maximum possible length the contents of the field in the XML can be.

In this trivial example, it's obviously 8 - I could figure that out by checking for {n} and assuming that's the length. In other patterns I could also check for * or + and assume unbounded - but I am looking for a more general approach that can be used to do this.

Note that the pattern string is not guaranteed to be compatible with .Net's Regex classes.

I also have access to the XmlSchemaPatternFacet class, which is what I'm using to parse the XSD in the first place, if that's any help.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Thanks for the title edit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll almost certainly need to parse the regular expression to achieve this. For example you could take the open-source regular expression parser in Saxon (which implements the right regex dialect). This creates a tree of subexpressions, and you could add a method to compute the maximum match length for each node in the tree. The `Operation` class, representing a node in the tree, already (in 9.6) has methods `getMatchLength()` and `getMinimumMatchLength()`, and it would be easy enough to add a `getMaximumMatchLength()` that works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

With these definitions:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ST_exactly8digitsString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="ST_upto8digitsString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

all of these will validate:

```
<upto8digitsString>12345678</upto8digitsString>
<upto8digitsString>12345</upto8digitsString>
<exactly8digitsString>12345678</exactly8digitsString>
```

these will not:

```
<exactly8digitsString>12345</exactly8digitsString>
<upto8digitsString>123456789</upto8digitsString>
```

Even though I guess you are looking for:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ST_anyNoDigitsString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

All of these match:

```
<anyNoDigitsString>12345678900000000</anyNoDigitsString>
<anyNoDigitsString>88</anyNoDigitsString>
<anyNoDigitsString></anyNoDigitsString>
<anyNoDigitsString>0</anyNoDigitsString>
```

Compared with other .Net regular expression, **[the XML schema regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) are limited in features**. Since they are only used to validate whether an entire element matches a pattern or not. Afaik, only [greedy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `?, *, +` and `{n,m}` are allowed.

Comment: the regex in my post was only an example. I'm looking for a general way to know, given the pattern from the xsd, what is the longest the entry in the xml could possibly be.

Comment: Question was unclear in the first place. I guess the purpose of validation is *self sufficient*. If your target is to have a certain limitation for strings, you *invent a pattern restriction*. If xml validation fails then it's obvious your length specifications were exceeded. You are going the other way round, using `XmlSchemaPatternFacet` to determine length, flawed imho. Just validate the xml with some patterns. If that works, expectations were met... It's useless doing some sort of inference over the length of a pattern.

Comment: thing is, I'm not just using the XSD to parse XML - I need to do something with a database, so I need to know what restrictions to put on the table - the information for which comes from the XSD, hence needing to know this information.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it would be very difficult. With embedded braces you will have to recursivly search for pattern length.

Edit: I found https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare that seems to fit your requirements.

```
var regex = @"((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)";
var xeger = new Xeger(regex);

var result = Regex.IsMatch(xeger.Generate(), regex);
```

Also i'm not sure it find the largest possible answer, but it can be a start.