# How to find out the maximum and minimum length of strings that match to a given regular expression

Tags: regex, string, algorithm

A theoretical question. I have a regex. I want to find the strings that match to this. How can i get the minimum and maximum length of these strings?

Comment: you need to the language builtin functions.

Comment: Min/Max length of a string isn't something you need regex for, you find your matches, and then find the lengths of these. I removed your language tags since your question doesn't directly require any of them

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649539/calculating-the-maximum-possible-length-for-a-string-matching-a-regular-expressi

Answer (score 5):

Convert the regular expression to an NFA (with epsilon transitions, if you like). Delete every state that cannot reach an accepting state (this might be a no-op). The minimum length is the length of a shortest path to an accepting state (use Dijkstra from the start state, where transitions with symbols have length 1 and epsilon transitions have length 0). Using a double-ended queue, this is linear-time. The maximum length is infinity iff there is a cycle. Otherwise, the transition graph is acyclic; use an algorithm for longest path in an acyclic graph.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to parse and analyse the regex.  For classical regexes it is pretty straight-forward to work out the bounds on the lengths.  If you include look-aheads and look-behinds it could get rather complicated, but the problem is tractable (I think).

I'm not aware of any library methods that would do this (in Java).  But that is hardly surprising.  The use-cases for this functionality must be few and far between.